# Minimal non-contiguous sequence of exactly k elements

Tags: algorithm

The problem I'm having can be reduced to:

> Given an array of `N`  positive numbers, find the non-contiguous sequence of exactly `K` elements with the minimal sum.
>
> Ok-ish: report the sum only. Bonus: the picked elements can be identified (at least one set of indices, if many can realize the same sum).

(in layman terms: pick any K *non-neighbouring* elements from N values so that their sum is minimal)

Of course, `2*K <= N+1` (otherwise no solution is possible), the problem is insensitive to positive/negative (just shift the array values with the `MIN=min(A...)` then add back `K*MIN` to the answer).

What I got so far (the naive approach):

1. select `K+2` indexes of the values closest to the minimum. I'm not sure about this, for `K=2` this seems to be the required to cover all the particular cases, but I don't know if it is required/sufficient for `K>2`******
2. brute force the minimal sum from the values of indices resulted at prev step respecting the non-contiguity criterion - if I'm right and `K+2` is enough, I can live brute-forcing a `(K+1)*(K+2)` solution space but, as I said. I'm not sure `K+2` is enough for `K>2` (if in fact `2*K` points are necessary, then brute-forcing goes out of window - the binomial coefficient `C(2*K, K)` grows prohibitively fast)

Any clever idea of how this can be done with minimal time/space complexity?

****** for `K=2`, a non-trivial example where 4 values closest to the absolute minimum are necessary to select the objective sum `[4,1,0,1,4,3,4]` - one cannot use the `0` value for building the minimal sum, as it breaks the non-contiguity criterion.

PS - if you feel like showing code snippets, C/C++ and/or Java will be appreciated, but any  language with decent syntax or pseudo-code will do <sub>(I reckon "decent syntax" excludes Perl, doesn't it?)</sub>

Comment: I would rephrase this as follows: In an array of numbers, find the **k** non-contiguous minimal elements (the fact that they would yield the minimal sum is a byproduct of finding those elements).

Comment: Are you sure that all k elements must be non-neighboring? Strictly speaking a non-continous sequence just means there's at least one gap between any of the elements.

Comment: @IngoBürk Absolutely sure. So sure that I provided the layman terms explanation, in which *non-neighboring* is emphasized.

Comment: @FDavidov "I would rephrase this as follows: In an array of numbers, find the k non-contiguous minimal elements" Maybe it is, maybe it isn't - I don't see how this pushed the solution ahead. Do you care to elaborate?

Comment: So, _you don't see..._ .Ok... Generate a sorted list of your nodes (from smallest to biggest) where each entry includes the value and its index in the original list. The lowest value is IN by definition. Then, start checking if the second is contiguous to the first or not, if no, add it to the list of nodes, otherwise move to the next,... You don't need to calculate the sum of different collections and find the one that yields the minimal value. Clearer now?

Comment: @FDavidov It will fail, because in some cases "The lowest value is IN by definition" is false. Check the example I provided: `K=2` for `[4,1,0,1,4,3,4]` the lowest value (`0`) is OUT.

Comment: Either you wrongly explained the algorithm or I misunderstood it or your last example is wrong. Under the constraint of non-contiguous and number of entries = 2, the MIN is **2**, not 0 (i.e. 2nd and 4th entries).

Comment: @FDavidov How should I understand your explanation of " Generate a sorted list of your nodes...including  the value and its index. **The lowest value is IN by definition.**"? Otherwise, of course the MIN is **2**, not 0, but this is because "the lowest value - that is the value of `0` at zero-based-index of `2` - is **not** IN".

Comment: Let's take your example: `[4,1,0,1,4,3,4]`. You create a list as follows: `[[0,3],[1,2],[1,4],[3,6],[4,1],[4,5],[4,7]]` (where [x,y] means (_value x is in position y_") and start collecting from this list checking if the next entry in the list collides with one of the already collected entries. You may need to repeat this 2 times (because taking "0" without any check might not give the best result, and hence you need to check if starting from the second entry does better).

Comment: @FDavidov "You may need to repeat this 2 times" Only 2 tiimes? Perhaps on the example provided 2 times is enough. How about the general case: how many times do I need to check? And when it is a good time to check and when can I go without checking? What is the time complexity of involved by checking?

Comment: Look, I'm not a mathematician not have the time to phase and prove a theorem. My only purpose was to try and give you some lines of thinking that may help you in resolving your problem. Beyond that, I'm afraid I can't help you. Sorry and good luck.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi over that approach, if `K` is very much less than `N/2`, it is guaranteed you will find your `K` elements in 1st half of the sorted array. Then in that case you can proceed by going breadth wise (instead of depth wise and backtracking) by calculating sum of 1st `N/2` cases by FDavidov's approach and going along the path of minimum of level 1

Comment: @FDavidov thanks for the intention, appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome. Still, I have the hunch that it may be worth checking my suggestion (no guarantees though).

Comment: @ritesht93 "it is guaranteed you will find your K elements in 1st half of the sorted array. " - if you look at my approach, I was hoping for better: in the the first step, I'm selecting a number of less than N/2 (hopefully, somewhere around K), then I'm working on these values/indices in step 2. So, more or less, exactly as FDavidov described, except that I'm doing a single pass over the input array to select/sort a smaller number of val/index, with a complexity of O(N*log(K)) instead of N*log(N). If K is small, then one gets a O(N) complexity  - for N in the 10^5, that's 1600% faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume input numbers are stored in array a[N]

Generic approach is DP: f(n, k) = min(f(n-1, k), f(n-2, k-1)+a[n])

It takes O(N*K) time and has 2 options:

- for lazy backtracking recursive solution O(N*K) space
- for O(K) space for forward cycle

In special case of big K there is another possibility:

- use recursive back-tracking
- instead of helper array of N*K size use map(n, map(k, pair(answer, list(answer indexes))))
- save answer and list of indexes for this answer
- instantly return MAX_INT if k>N/2

This way you'll have lower time than O(N*K) for K~=N/2, something like O(N*log(N)). It will increase up to O(N*log(N)*K*log(K)) for small K, so decision between general approach or special case algorithm is important.

Comment: Thanks, I set my bones to work, see what I can get from this. What is you feeling of guts, *for small K-es*, can one do a preselection scan and retain only a sequence to enter the DP without risk? Surely heaps of those values won't contribute to he result. Suppose I'd select a K lowest values + left/right neighs (tracking their index position), collate them as an input  to DP, a kind of "representative of the original" ... would there be risk? Should I look for more than K? (space complexity is what I'm hunting now, I'm almost sure your suggestion is sound).

Comment: Taking lowest K values looks promising, but I'd go for 2*K lowest values+neightbors if time for DP is critical. But if you are all for memory complexity and use low enough K, you can go straight through DP with forward cycle. In this case you need to keep only n-2, n-1 slices of K size each to form n slice (total memory will be ~K*K because solution candidate lists can be up to K elements in length). So you can process input on the fly, not even keeping all input values in memory (only candidates for solution in corresponding lists).

Answer (score 2):

There should be a dynamic programming approach to this.

Work along the array from left to right. At each point i, for each value of j from 1..k, find the value of the right answer for picking j non-contiguous elements from 1..i. You can work out the answers at i by looking at the answers at i-1, i-2, and the value of array[i]. The answer you want is the answer at n for an array of length n. After you have done this you should be able to work out what the elements are by back-tracking along the array to work out whether the best decision at each point involves selecting the array element at that point, and therefore whether it used array[i-1][k] or array[i-2][k-1].

Comment: I'm not sure how DP over `j in [1..K]` is going to help. To apply DP, the sub-problems answer must not change if I'm looking at it from the next level. In the example I provided, the sub-problem `j=1` will place the objective to index 2 (val `0`). If I'm adding another, the prev sub-problem is not going to help - either I keep it and get a bad result, or throw it away and I'm no better tan before. Or... maybe I didn't get very well what you mean?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi: We are trying to calculate f(i, j), the largest non-contiguous sum of exactly j elements that can be achieved without using only elements at positions <= i.  Now either (A) there is a best position that includes i, in which case it must not include i-1; or (B) no best position includes i, in which case we may include i-1.  So this can indeed be done using mcdowella's DP: f(i, j) = max(A, B), where A = x[i] + f(i-2, j-1) and B = f(i-1, j).  (You need to also consider base case(s).)

Comment: @j_random_hacker well, you are right. A bit confusing at first because, while reading the textual explanation, I stumbled over the dependency on `j=1..k` and totally missed the 'answers at i-1, i-2, and the value of array[i]' part. I must admit that when Alexander's answer came in, my first reaction was "But... it's evident, how could I have missed that?"